# Please, help to get a value for a webelement

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to ask the help - I need to get the value from WebElement 'input'. I tried general methods like getText(), but it doesn't work. Then I tried JavaScript in console and in console it works fine:

```
"document.evaluate('(//div[@id="CreateOrderBlock"]//input[@class="el-input__inner"])[3]',document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value;"
```

But how to handle it in the test? (Selenium WebDriver + Java) How to convert it to int java?
Maybe I need JavascriptExecutor , but in any case I would like to get an example.
I tried like:

```
 String summValueString = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.evaluate('(//div[@id='CreateOrderBlock']//input[@class='el-input__inner'])[3]',document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value;");
```

```
<div class="input el-input">
<!---->
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" rows="2" validateevent="true" class="el-input__inner">
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an **`input`** text, please use the `.getAttribute("value")` method instead of `.getText()`.